# Range Fill Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Good day!
There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
start_range  varcahar2(10),
end_range varcahar2(10),
val_range NUMBER(10)
);
```

At the initial stage, we filled in two fields: start_range and end_range.

```
start_range = a1;
end_range = a5;
```

Can you fill a completely different table in the range `a1-a5` `(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)` in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a hierarchical query.

Test case:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     start_range  VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     end_range    VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     val_range    NUMBER (10)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test
  2       VALUES ('a1', 'a5', NULL);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TEST
  2       VALUES ('L4819201', 'L4819205', NULL);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

START_RANG END_RANGE   VAL_RANGE
---------- ---------- ----------
a1         a5
L4819201   L4819205
```

Query:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test2 (val)
  2     SELECT    SUBSTR (start_range, 1, 1)
  3            || TO_CHAR (
  4                  (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (start_range, '\d+$'))
  5                   + COLUMN_VALUE
  6                   - 1))
  7               AS val
  8       FROM test
  9            CROSS JOIN
 10            TABLE (
 11               CAST (
 12                  MULTISET (
 13                         SELECT LEVEL
 14                           FROM DUAL
 15                     CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 16                                     TO_NUMBER (
 17                                        REGEXP_SUBSTR (end_range, '\d+$'))
 18                                   - TO_NUMBER (
 19                                        REGEXP_SUBSTR (start_range, '\d+$'))
 20                                   + 1) AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
 21      WHERE start_range = '&start_range';
Enter value for start_range: a1

5 rows created.

SQL> /
Enter value for start_range: L4819201

5 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER BY val;

VAL
----------
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
L4819201
L4819202
L4819203
L4819204
L4819205

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I write this answer to table2 ?? to the VAL line

Comment: Using INSERT, Andrii. `insert into your_table (val) select substr(start_range ... `. I've edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, another last question when I write start_range = L4819201;
end_range = L4819205; it doesn't work

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You'll have to enter `L4819201` instead of `a1` in line #4.

Comment: I changed there

Comment: Aha; I understood that you want to subtract end and start value & base result on that. OK, fixed. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you for helping me)) But I already 2 hours deal with your code, but it turns out so only I write start_range = L4819222; end_range = L4819235 It records 4 lines(((Can you help?

Comment: Lines #17 and 19 have to be modified; I've already done that in my example. The `+` sign is missing, here: `'\d+$'`

Comment: And is it possible to write it down simultaneously in two tables ??

Comment: Theoretically, yes - you'd use `insert all`. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT PREFIX || ( START_RANGE + LEVEL - 1 )
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(START_RANGE, '^[[:alpha:]]+') AS PREFIX,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(START_RANGE, '\d+$') AS START_RANGE,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(END_RANGE, '\d+$') AS END_RANGE
        FROM
            TEST
    )
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= END_RANGE - START_RANGE + 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I am assuming that your start and end range have same prefix with format(string||number)

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b46cec891cc0c83486196894351cae9)**

Cheers!!

Comment: hi, if i have multiple entries? it searches in all ranges, and I need specific ones

Comment: And is it possible to write it down simultaneously in two tables ??

Comment: hi, i want to thank you again for your help and ask for one more,  when using extreme chills as "L00000000" and "L00000010", I get: L1, L2, L3 ... but I wanted to see: L00000000, L00000001, L00000002, ..., can you help me in this ??