# Range fill table in form apex oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Good day! I have a fill form, the form is `P1_FIRST` and `P1_LAST`, I want after filling them in. 
For example `P1_FIRST = L4819222 and P1_LAST = L4819225`. 
I press Create. 
In the `Test2` table, records `L4819222, L4819223, L4819224, L4819225` were created.Thank you for your help

I have asked for help before and they helped me, but the option was suitable when the extreme values were already in the table. In this variant, the extreme values are only in the form. 
   [Range Fill Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726099/range-fill-table/57726194?noredirect=1#comment101906374_57726194)

Comment: If these numbers are always sequential you might consider using an Identity column, or a sequence if you're DB hasn't made it to 12c yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference whether you use values stored in a table or item values, query remains the same. Actually, it is even a little bit simpler.

As you already have those items, now

- create a button

  - let it Submit the page
- create a process which will run when you press the button
- process will perform this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO test2 (val)
  SELECT    SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, 1, 1)
        || TO_CHAR (
              (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
               + LEVEL
               - 1))
           AS val
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                  TO_NUMBER (
                     REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_LAST, '\d+$'))
               - TO_NUMBER (
                     REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P1_FIRST, '\d+$'))
               + 1;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tested it and it works, but it doesn't record the last number. When tested in Apex, it performed as you said, but when generating, it formed several similar variables. I attached it all to Before Page Submit/Set Value/PL-SQLFunction Body

Comment: Aha; the last `+ 1` is missing; I've added it now. I don't understand the rest of your message (starting from "several similar variables").

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me a lot. I ask a lot of weasels because I am new to Apex. With the rest I have already figured out)

Comment: I so understand that "SUBSTR (: P1_FIRST, 1, 1)" this part corresponds to the types of line by which I will generate. And is it possible to make this part a little more versatile ??? for example, if I type L4819225 it will work fine, but if I type AL4819225 it will not work correctly, to work correctly you need to do "SUBSTR (: P1_FIRST, 1, 2)", and is it possible to do it automatically ??

Comment: Regular expressions will help. Use `regexp_substr(:P1_FIRST, '[[:alpha:]]+')` instead.

Comment: I want to thank for homework, but I want to ask again when I use extreme chills as "L00000000" and "L00000010", I get out: L1, L2, L3 ... but I wanted to see: L00000000, L00000001, L00000002 ,. .. can you help me in this ??

Comment: Use LPAD to fill it with leading zeros.

Comment: regexp_substr(:P1_FIRST, '[[:alpha:]]+'||  || lpad('\1', 4, '0'))    So?